# Gerund or infinitive?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, gerunds

Is this possible to use the infinitive in these sentences?And how to form the last one? I simply can not do it.
In brackets I wrote variants which to my mind suit it best.

1.Not **overdoing(or to overdo?)** discipline and **helping (or to help?)** children understand the reasons behind the discipline by explaining it to them is important.

2.When children are playing,parents or caregivers should supervise clsely enough **to monitor(or monitoring?)** how the children are behaving and be prepared to teach them appropriate social behaviour.

3.They risk their child **growing up(or to grow up)** to think that such behaviour is acceptible.

4.**(you/begin/a conversation)** may not make you instantly popular,but if you consistently focus on helping people feel comfortable by talking to them and smiling at them,you will notice that people will be more friendly towards you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm reasonably comfortable with either, so long as it's consistent in both places, but I prefer overdoing... helping....
2. to monitor works best for me
3. ...growing up...
4. Beginning a conversation...

My technical grammar isn't good enough to quite know *why* I prefer those forms, but they're the most comfortable to me as native Br E.